# facebook send button is not working with localhost

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsp

I have included the following code in my jsp page,

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.172.28.188.com" data-font="tahoma"></div>
```

But it is not working,I think it is not accepting the data-href as "http://www.172.28.188.com",Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Have you got SSL setup on your localhost?

Comment: From localhost you can't do social plugins

Comment: @sam - You are **100% wrong** my friend.  You can most definitely use social plugins locally.

Comment: @Lix-I don't know. How to check?

Comment: You can tell if you are using SSL if you are using `https` and not `http`.  What you might want to try is to explicitly specify loading the SDK over `https`.  Change the url to include the protocol - `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1`

Comment: @SamArulRaj-Then how can i do it?

Comment: i am using http,k i will try and tell u the result

Answer (score 0):

There 2 things to consider here.

1. have u tried to remove the www from the url.
2. is the fbid and fbkey configured for the url u specified. https://developers.facebook.com/apps

check your configuration again